# Every time I run Vmware, I get this error: Error While powering on: The VMware Authorization Service is not running

Tags: vmware-workstation

Error While powering on: The VMware Authorization Service is not running.

To fix this error, I go to:

"Start / Control Panel / Administrative Tools / Services, clicked on VMware Authorization Service in the list & click the Start link on the left."

But I have to do this every time I want to use the Vitual Machine.

Does anyone know a permanent solution?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

go to `Start > Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Services` double click on `VMware Authorization Service` a window will open.

It will look something like this

[image]

In that window select Automatic from the drop-down menu near to `Startup Type:`. Then click on the `OK` button to save the change.

Comment: @user177931  I think the right stack for these kind of questions are http://superuser.com/ . Next time if u have any OS related question please ask in http://superuser.com/

Comment: Hi, that did'nt work i still have to go into services and restart it :(

Comment: right below there is link `Help me to configure service start option`. click on the link and follow the documentation. If it doesn't help you, let me know

Comment: Hi again, that does'nt work for me.

Comment: After Changing Type to Manual . I had to "Start" the service to get rid of the error

Comment: @DeenbandhuPrasad You should set `Startup Type` to `Automatic` Not `Manual`.

Comment: While my error message did not provided any clue, [VMware Player – “Error while powering on: Internal error"], starting VMWARE Authorization Service quickly solved my issue. Thanks to you and Google (for pointing out this page as a good solution)

Answer (score 27):

I resolved this by starting VMware Workstation as Administrator.